# Extjs application is crashed when dynamically adding one defective item

Tags: javascript, class, object, extjs, crash

When an item is dynamically added to the created component, if there is an error in the item, the application crashes.

This problem does not exist when the item is not created.

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    initComponent: function () {
        //  make error
        // this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Application',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
    },

    defaults: {
        margin: 10,
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-cog',
        handler: function (btn) {
            let mainPanel = btn.up('panel'),
                item = Ext.create('Test');

            // bug
            mainPanel.add(item);
        },
    }],
});
```

[sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3g42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange problem, because you are trying to find out if the developer did something wrong during runtime.

But anyways - here is one solution for your problem:

```
        handler: function (btn) {
            let mainPanel = btn.up('panel'),
                item = Ext.create('Test');

            // bug testing
            if(Ext.isDefined(item) && Ext.isObject(item.layout)) {
                mainPanel.add(item);
            } else {
                console.error(item.id + ' could not be added because of an error I made.')
            }
        },
```

Comment: Yes. An error in the package of other developers should not interfere with the main application.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If so - please mark it as answered. If not - let me know how this does not work.

Comment: You should not use it untested - right? Though sometimes you might not be in charge for testing, I would dump the package from other developers. It's unsave to use those and there is no I can prevent this. My solution checks for the layout, because, that might break it.

Comment: If the component type is Window, it still gives an error.

Comment: You must not add the `let item` inside the try catch block. If defined above you can use `Ext.isDefined(item) && Ext.isObject(item.layout)`

Comment: Just create window by "Ext.create()"  code.

Comment: `Ext.create('myWindow').show()` will create the window centered on top of the viewport. `MyPanel.add({xtype: 'window'})` centers the window on top of the panel.

Comment: This is a good answer to prevent an error that stops the entire application but does not specify what error has occurred.

Comment: It would have been helpful, if you had specified A) a question in your post and B) being more specific. From my Answer you can get everthing you need. You can find out more by investigating the item. But from a framework perspective, you should test your application before you ship it and hence find out why someone missed to call the parent method. If the answer is good, please mark it as answered. If you need more help, hire someone to help you.